# PLSql - do not allow user to change password within 4 hours from last update

Tags: plsql

Right now we are not capturing the last password update timestamp. What is the best way to capture the password update time and then what is the best way to not allow user to change password within 4 hours from last changed timestamp.

Should I create procedure to capture password change time or should I use triggers?

Should I create procedure to check and send message if the user tries to change the password within 4 hours from last change or can we do this using triggers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the password used in order to connect to the Oracle database?

Comment: No, this is for one of our application, we want to keep a control to users so that they don't change their password within 4 hours from last update. Our application uses Oracle db

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but based on my understanding of the information you have provided, why not store the timestamp of the password change in the database and in your application retrieve that timestamp from the database and compare it with the current system time. If the difference is less than four hours, the application should inform the user that they cannot change their password.